# Why is my meta data not showing in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Here is the code I added in my functions.php file:

```
// Add a datetime field to the WordPress user meta.
function update_user_profile() {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_id = $current_user->ID;

  $datetime = current_time('timestamp');
  add_user_meta($user_id, 'profile_updated', $datetime, true);
}
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'update_user_profile');
```

For some reason it worked one time then when I tested another user for update, the profile_updated meta did not show.

I am trying to show a timestamp of when a user edits/updates their profile.

Comment: What happens if you use `false` instead of `true`? And what happens if you use update_user_meta() instead of add_user_meta()? Please add those clarifications to your question by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score 0):

If the fourth parameter of [`add_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/) is `true`, it will not overwrite an existing meta key. Additionally, the code is using the ID of the current user, rather than the ID of the user edited. The callback for [`edit_user_profile_update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_user_profile_update/) has one parameter, `$user_id`, that should be used (untested):

```php
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', static function ( int $user_id ) {
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'profile_updated', current_time( 'timestamp' ), true );
} );
```

I suspect that you want that value to change every time a user's profile is updated, which means `add_user_meta()` needs to change to [`update_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/):

```php
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'profile_updated', current_time( 'timestamp' ) );
```